# How can i log retries as warnings, in Kafka blocking and non-blocking retries

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How can i log retries as warnings, in `Kafka` blocking and non-blocking retries. I want to log the exception causing the retry, and the attempts. I know I can do it for non-blocking retries using a `producerinterceptor`. But I don't think it is the correct way to do it. I would like to intercept at exception time, so I can control the logging level and message, before the log is created.

Comment: Although not entirely related, this discussion can shed some light on it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2992. Could you create an issue in the project repository? This might be an enhancement that we can explore a solution for.

Comment: Thanks for creating the discussion. More details here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/3008